# Undefined is not a function use of this and self

Tags: javascript

When the following ViewModel function is executed then the error *Uncaught TypeError: self.deleteInvisibleColumns is not a function* is raised - why is this?

```
function ViewModel(vm) {
    var self = this;

    this.rows = ko.observableArray(vm.Rows);
    self.deleteInvisibleColumns();

    this.deleteInvisibleColumns = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.Rows.length; i++) {
            var row = vm.Rows[i];

            var keys = Object.keys(row);
            for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                if (vm.VisibleColumns.indexOf(keys[k]) === (-1)) {
                    delete row[keys[k]];
                };
            };
        };
    };
```

Comment: calling a function before it's defined ?

Comment: You may be a bit confused about how *hoisting* works...? Not all Javascript code is randomly reordered. Some things do indeed still execute sequentially.

Comment: Doh! Thanks Hacketo, I forgot Javascript is not compiled - too long in C#!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove the function definition before callint it
2. Use "self" for both function definition and calling it

   ```
   function ViewModel(vm) {

       var self = this;

       this.rows = ko.observableArray(vm.Rows);

       self.deleteInvisibleColumns = function () {
           for (var i = 0; i < vm.Rows.length; i++) {
              var row = vm.Rows[i];

              var keys = Object.keys(row);
              for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                 if (vm.VisibleColumns.indexOf(keys[k]) === (-1)) {
                    delete row[keys[k]];
                 };
             };
         };
       };

       self.deleteInvisibleColumns();
   };
   ```

Comment: Why define a function and then call it, when you could go with the for-loops directly? Otherwise you'll end up redefining the same function over and over again.. Just remove the row starting the inner function and the matching brace.

Comment: @diynevala It's not my code. I guess that if Rob Bowman put this code in a function, he may want to reuse it in another place.

Comment: I understand it is not your code. Isn't that function only accessible inside the ViewModel-function, so it is not really reusable (unless used IN the same function)?